# std::transform Vector For Euclidean Distance

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I would like to find the optimal approach to computing the Euclidean distance of some points in a vector.  I am trying to use a std::transform to square each number, then pass this function as an argument into std::accumulate.  Is this the most efficient way?  As of right now my implementation has a bug, the error is:

```
in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::accumulate<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, int, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *> >' requested
      here
  cout << std::sqrt(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), square))) << endl;
```

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
#include<cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int square(int n) {return n*n;}

int
main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::vector<int> v1;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {v.push_back(i);}
  v1.resize(v.size());
  //std::transform (v.begin(), v.end(), v1.begin(), square);                                                                                                                         
  //std::copy(v.begin(), v1.begin(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));                                                                                                        


  //cout << std::sqrt(std::accumulate(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0)) << endl;                                                                                                             
  cout << std::sqrt(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), square))) << endl;

  //for(auto it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); it++)                                                                                                                                  
    //{cout << *it << endl;}                                                                                                                                                         

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first `transform` then `accumulate` the transformed vector

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), square);                                                                                                       
cout << std::sqrt(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0)) << endl;
```

as [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) does not (yet) return a range. If/when [Eric Niebler](http://ericniebler.com/)'s [ranges](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) will make it to C++17, you'll be able to write this code much more concisely and elegantly.

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5711e5107c5acbb)

In terms of efficiency, I'd say it's quite efficient. Don't worry about micro-optimization unless you know (from a profiler) that you hit a "hot" area of your code.

Comment: Thanks! Question:  one thing I noticed was that there's a 4-argument accumulation which accepts a function as its 4th parameter.  Is it not possible to combine accumulate and transform in a single step?

Comment: @nietsnegttiw Not yet... wait for *ranges*, see the updated edit.

Comment: @nietsnegttiw That fourth argument is for defining the accumulation function; By default `+` is used, but you can use other operations.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what [`std::inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) is for.

```
#include<iostream> // cout
#include<vector>   // vector
#include<numeric>  // inner_product, iota
#include<cmath>    // sqrt

using std::cout;

int
main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(10);
  std::iota(begin(v), end(v), 0);

  double result = std::sqrt(std::inner_product(begin(v), end(v), begin(v), 0));

  cout << result << '\n';    
}
```